# Why can't travel through a closed timelike curve violate the Novikov self-consistency principle?

Tags: causality, time-travel, closed-timelike-curve

The Novikov self-consistency principle prevents a paradox in which a billiard ball is sent to its past through a closed timelike curve (allowed under general relativity) such that it collides with its past self and prevents it from entering.

Imagine a setup where the ball, as soon as it exits in the past, hits a switch that closes a gate across the entrance. What's to stop that from creating a paradox? There's no alternate trajectory for the ball; the switch can be a plate that covers the exit so that the ball can't avoid hitting it.

Comment: The point of the principle is that the probability of such an event must be zero, and so any model of the Universe in which this is allowed cannot be correct.  Given that it's easy to imagine a situation like this in a Universe where arbitrary closed timelike curves are possible, then the easiest conclusion is that closed timelike curves are not possible.

Comment: When physicists analyze scenarios involving wormholes, my memory is that they stick to situations where they are free to choose arbitrary boundary conditions in the region *outside* the [Cauchy horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_horizon) which marks the boundary of the region of spacetime that can contain closed timelike curves. If that's the case, then you can't necessarily assume it's possible to set up any sort of device arbitrarily close to the wormhole, there could for ex. be interference from objects whose whole existence was a loop (Novikov and Lossev labeled these "Jinn").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no guarantee that the Novikov self-consistency principle is correct. However, it has been studied and has some good support in the literature.

Basically, what it says is that the local physics in and around a wormhole are what we expect of the local physics elsewhere. The wormhole doesn't introduce any new local physics. And globally the only permissible solutions are ones that are self-consistent. Other solutions have probability of 0.

One issue with the self-consistency principle is that it is generally not unique. Often, and perhaps always, there are multiple trajectories that are self-consistent with any given initial condition. There is no rule for choosing among all possible self-consistent trajectories from a given initial condition.

In your case, it would seem that one obvious self consistent possibility would be that the very same plate which the ball cannot avoid would unavoidably block the ball from entering. Another self-consistent possibility is that the switch you envision is not physically possible (meaning that no switch on the exit can change something on the entrance). Another self-consistent possibility is that the switch is possible but requires time to operate and the ball always manages to get through in time (I like that one, it seems exciting). You could of course add complications to address each of those, and someone else could provide another self consistent possibility to address your new complications, etc.

In the end, we have no way to prove the conjecture short of testing it. If it is correct then there will always be some self-consistent possibility remaining and one of those will occur. A non-self-consistent scenario would be impossible to physically build. If a non-self-consistent scenario is produced then the conjecture is not correct.

Comment: One could argue that the question is not even one of science. Science is the rational explanation of natural observations. Closed timelike curves have not been observed, hence there is no pressure on science to even make a statement about them. That, by the way, is already true for wormholes.

Comment: @FlatterMann yes, I agree. No observation contradicts either stance on the conjecture.

Comment: @FlatterMann Science includes questions about theoretical consequences of theories even if they’d be hard to verify, no? Or do you also think examples like “what is beyond the event horizon of a black hole” or “what is the long term future of the cosmos” aren’t scientific questions?

Comment: @Hypnosifl It does? A physical theory is an approximate description of reality. It fits within its range of application and is total nonsense outside of it. Newton and Maxwell, for instance, predict that stable matter can't exist... and yet, here we are. What's the point of asking Newton and Maxwell to make predictions about matter that they can't make? Absolutely nothing.

Comment: @FlatterMann - But physicists have theoretical arguments for where existing theories like general relativity are likely to become significantly incorrect (the Planck scale for example) and where they are probably accurate, so general relativity would likely be wrong in the immediate neighborhood of a singularity in a black hole (including the inner horizon of a rotating black hole), but would likely be accurate in parts of the interior that aren't too close to a singularity. I suppose predicting the far future of the universe requires a better understanding of dark energy, though.

Comment: @Hypnosifl One can't make scientific statements about things that haven't been observed and that are probably unobservable. Anybody who tells me that he has a hunch about what happens "inside" the event horizon of a black hole needs to re-read the definition of science IMHO. That doesn't mean we can't do black hole physics, but it requires a gravitational wave observatory or something like the Event Horizon Telescope.

Comment: This question isn’t about black holes, it is about closed timelike curves. They are not the same.

Comment: @Dale I realize that, but I was disputing the broad comment by FlatterMann about what is and isn't "science".

Comment: @FlatterMann - "Science" has no canonical description, I think the only good way to try to define it is by looking at what the scientific community has actually seen as part of science historically, and theoretical extrapolations of existing theories have always been part of that (for ex., Einstein could not have hoped to actually try to catch up to a light beam and see if its speed would change for an observer with a fast enough velocity, but a thought-experiment about this idea helped to point to the theoretical inconsistency between Maxwell and Galilean physics which helped lead to SR).

Comment: Similarly, apparent inconsistencies between what quantum physics says about entangled particles and what would theoretically be measured on either side of an event horizon (the [black hole information paradox](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.05864)) are seen as possible theoretical pointers to a theory of quantum gravity, which could then be testable in regions outside the event horizon. So even if claims about the interior region are not scientifically testable, they may be an important part of the theoretical development of new theories which are testable in other cases.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Science is the rational description of natural observations but I don't want to get into a discussion about that in the comment section. Unless somebody can observe a closed time-like curve, the concept is simply not scientific.

Comment: (cont.) Even if we focus on "scientifically testable" rather than broader notions of science, when you say "One can't make scientific statements about things that haven't been observed and that are probably unobservable", do you really mean to rule out things that would *in principle* be testable by a sufficiently long-lived civilization, but just aren't testable in the near-term future, like my other example of theories about the long-term future of the cosmos?

Comment: @FlatterMann "Science is the rational description of natural observations" I would say the best short description of science is that it's about theories that are tested based on natural observations, but may have consequences that go beyond them (allowing us to make judgments about the likelihood of unobserved facts based on theories that have a good track record of predicting observed ones). As another example, you think it's unscientific to believe that prehistoric organisms on Earth, say trilobites, had DNA based cells?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Let's make a chatroom if you want me to explain my views on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not quite limited to closed timelike curves. In mathematical terms, we want our equations of motion to be [*well-posed problems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem).

The idea goes at least back to [Hadamard](https://illposed.net/hadamard.pdf). Physics is usually based on the idea that a physical system is based on some initial conditions (how the system is at a given time) and an equation of motion (telling you how the system is at any other given time), such that at the original time, the system is in the same condition as the initial conditions, and at all times it obeys the equations of motion.

Well-posed problems have a list of various conditions to make sense of them physically, although some of them are perhaps a bit of wishful thinking, but we want the system to have at most one solution to the equations of motion (so that it is predictable), and at least one solution. If there are no solution, you simply enter in a contradiction : you observe the system at some initial time, but there are actually no solutions admitting the system being in that state. Therefore, the equation of motion that you are using does not actually describe the behaviour of this system.

This problem occurs for a variety of reasons, some of them due to causality, others just due to some specific types of differential equations not being well-posed problems in general. Short of some very radical changes to how physics is done, it is assumed that the equations involved must be well-posed problems, and this can indeed be a problem with closed timelike curves (although not all spacetimes with closed timelike curves are such ill-posed problems).